# Paging 3 PagingSource class doesn't loads at all

Tags: android, kotlin, android-paging, kotlin-flow, android-paging-3

`PagingSource` class doesn't loads. I set breakpoints and logs inside `load` method, but it skip all.

And in pager config it skips `MediaListPagingSource(mediaApi)` line.

When I call retrofit method that load data separately it's actually loads!

My setup of Pager

```
Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE,
            enablePlaceholders = false
        ),
        pagingSourceFactory = {
            MediaListPagingSource(mediaApi) // mediaApi - retrofit interface
        }
    ).flow
```

Comment: Did you hook up this flow to an adapter or some other presenter api using `.submitData`?

Comment: @dlam I'm consuming this flow in ViewModel using viewModelScope.launch in init block of viewModel

Comment: Can you share how you consume this flow and call submitData?

Comment: Same issue I am facing how did you resolved can you please let me know? @dlam

Comment: Same issue I am facing how did you resolved can you please let me know? @MaxTurchin

Comment: @TanishqChawda Can you start a new question and share your code. The issue here was the person was not actually collecting the Flow so Paging did not start loading / displaying data, but it's impossible to tell what your issue is without seeing code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution.

I'm using Jetpack Compose and need to call `.collectAsLazyPagingItems()` in composable function to actually collect data.

Thanks [@dlam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1452382/dlam) for hint.